# using getNotes with blanks inbetween?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm trying to use a for loop to change values and to add notes to the ones that I change. since I'm doing it through arrays and not each row individually, my question is, is it possible to get where there isnt a note on the cell to be nothing in the array?

It's through the google scripts system, I've tried looking everywhere but can't find anything on the subject, hoping there's a wizard here.

edit: snippet of script

```
  function CheckHours() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of PNC Roster');
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var response;
var hoursList = [];
var notesList = [];
var bmidRange = sheet.getRange("L:L").getValues();
var notesRange = sheet.getRange("J:J").getNotes();


for (var i = 0; i < lastrow; i++) {
      if (bmidRange[i] > 1) {
        //response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('InsertWebsite/?bm=' + bmidRange[i] + '&fr=7');
        var seconds = 59378;
        var hours = seconds/60/60;
        hoursList.push([hours]);
        var note = "Activity Check performed: "+  new Date() + "\n\n" + notesRange[i];
        notesList.push([note]);
        Logger.log(hours);            
      } else if(bmidRange[i] == "") { 
         notesList.push('INSERT BATTLEMETRICS ID');
      } else { 
        hoursList.push(bmidRange[i]);
        notesList.push(notesRange[i]);
      }
}
sheet.getRange("J:J").offset(0, 0, hoursList.length).setNotes(notesList);
sheet.getRange("J:J").offset(0, 0, hoursList.length).setValues(hoursList);
}
```

What I'm trying to do when I'm pushing the cell values is that they get an appropriate note along with them, but because the variable notesRange is not the same amount as getValues gets, then where there is no notes, instead having a null value in the array basically, is this possible??

Comment: Do you have an example of your script? What's your question here - are you trying to make sure there are no notes added if the cell hasn't been edited?

Comment: @ross What I'm trying to do when I'm pushing the cell values is that they get an appropriate note along with them, but because the variable notesRange is not the same amount as getValues gets, then where there is no notes, instead having a null value in the array basically, is this possible?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, in the current state there's no way of running this, your `for` loop is based off of `var lastrow` but the variable doesn't exist in the code you provided.

Comment: I've added the full code.

Comment: Try `Logger.log(bmidRange.length === notesRange.length)`

Comment: @TheMaster The ranges are equal to each other but the lengths of the arrays are not, that's my issue.

Comment: I don't believe you. `getValues()` array length should be  equal to `getNotes()` array length regardless of blanks. Does the above log true or false?

Comment: The length of the values array and notes array are not the same, because where there is no notes, instead of adding a blank in the array, it just skips it, that's the issue, is there another way?

Comment: @Lemmen That's not the issue. I tested it and I got blanks in the array as expected,  when there is no note. Values array length is also equal to the notes array length. If you still say otherwise, prove it. Provide a [mre] that we can test and confirm the issue. My minimal reproducible example above in the comments- `Logger.log(...)` returns true. Does it not return true for you?

Comment: Why don't you describe the problem instead of describing what you think is the problem?